# Blender 2.8 All menus disappeared

Tags: interface

Due to unknown reasons all my menus disappear, how can I bring them back?

[image: no menus]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> .

Answer (score 5):

The problem you faces was caused by the combination of:
**<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>**+**<kbd>Alt</kbd>**+**<kbd>Space</kbd>**
You can find the function in the **Blender Preferences->Keymap**:
[image]

Using that combination you go from:
[image]

to:
[image]
*it maximizes the area depending on where you hover the mouse when pressing*

Comment: Yes! This is the right one!

Answer (score 2):

I had to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>Space</kbd>
Blender version 3.2.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it somewhat.
Steps I followed.

Open a startup file and do: File->Defaults->Load Factory Settings.
Then, File->Open.
In this browse menu untick Load UI, at the bottom left. Open your file.

Luckily your top menu is back and you can continue.